# web dev looking for some suggestions on this amateur logo design

Tags: logo, critique

I'm a junior web developer. I'm actually in the process of building a personal website and I decided to design myself a logo first. This is the first logo I have designed or let alone use Illustrator, and this is the result.

[image]
The Letter J is my first name John and the "angled brackets" denote the HTML open and angled brackets. I've positioned it to look like an S which is my last name and the other two slanted lines are there so there is more to the angled brackets.

I'm planning to have a dark background layout for my website, and red being my favorite color, decided to fill the background with it so that the logo stands out.

I was planning to type in my name in there with an "Inder" font however I'm going to put my name in the intro section so opted out of it.

On the right side, I'm not sure if that is. Initially thought of placing a vertical line with a stroke of 5pt but decided with this.

I'm really not sure about that brush stroke I'm planning to remove it. what do you guys think? Should I include my full name in this? Should I remove the brush stroke on the right?

Any suggestions on improving my design?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE. My personal opinion: I think it looks really cool and I'm impressed that this is your first attempt at logo design! Some users are voting to close this question as being to subjective though. Maybe [this](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) can help you narrow down your question.

Comment: as @Wolff has suggetsed - you should edit to narrow this one or it'll get closed fast. It's not that all critique questions are anathema, it's that there are specific parameters - hence the link in Wolff's comment. Please review and edit - I also am impressed and would like to answer, but you'll need to edit to avoid closure.

Comment: "Your question must be phrased in such a way that answers can be objectively voted on by the community.  

Keep in mind specifically what kind of critique feedback you are looking for.

Your question should encourage answers which explain their reasoning and back up any subjective statements with experience or recognized authorities.
While your question should give us an idea of your own style, it should also encourage fair and impartial answers."